# Why is my fragment shader receiving an attribute out the bounds I set?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, opengl-3

I have a large number of textured square tiles (composed of two adjacent triangles) being rendered with no MSAA. All tiles are touching in a grid-like fashion and have 32 units width on a 1280x720 unit canvas.

```
*******
*   / * 32 units
* /   *
*******
32 units
```

When rendering and smoothly moving the camera, lines show between the borders of each tile but, to my surprise, this still occurred even when I hard-coded the fragment color to black. This suggests that it is not the texture atlas bleeding between tiles as often happens.

The texture atlas is 2048x2048 pixels, and each tile is 128x128 pixels within. I am targeting the 2nd row, 2nd column, of my atlas thus my UV coordinates are set to 0.125, 0.125 (top left tile) to 0.1875, 0.1875 (bottom right tile) for every tile, and this is *exactly* what I uploaded within my buffer.

With the following fragment shader, all glitch lines turn red instead of the bleeding previously seen:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec2 v_uv;
out vec4 f_color;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture(tex, v_uv);

    // Use the color black for every fragment
    if (color.a >= 0.0) { // Always TRUE
        color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    // Check if the given v_uv is within the bound
    if (v_uv.x < 0.125) {
        color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    f_color = vec4(color.x, color.y, color.z, color.a);
}
```

Note the test to see if the UV is within the bounds. Red lines appear which suggests that, despite requesting the attribute values between 0.125 to 0.1875, the shader is receiving ~0.12499 instead. This makes no sense as a standard floating point should be able to hold 0.125 exactly.

**Why is my fragment shader receiving a slightly incorrect value when a floating point should be able to precisely hold exactly 0.125 and 0.1875 without error?**

Example video of this shader and the red lines with dozens of black tiles: https://gfycat.com/PlushScientificAlligator

This is running with GLFW, glad, OpenGL 3.3, GLSL 330, and C++.

Here are some additional details:

Vertex shader, mostly pass-through and simply multiples the vertices by my projection. It does receive any invalid UV coordinates, as tested:

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 projection;

layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 uv;

out vec2 v_uv;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    v_uv = uv;
}
```

Vertex array composed of:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(index, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), nullptr);
```

I am using two buffers: a position and a UV buffer both. All data is re-uploaded every frame. The flickering only occurs when the camera is moved and at certain positions.

A typical frame is composed of the following trace:

[image: Frame call trace]

Update projection uniform, upload UV data, bind texture, upload position data, bind vertex array, and finally, drawing of the array via GL_TRIANGLES, from 0 to the total count. Very standard and simple.

It is almost as if the camera position changes the way the UV coordinates are handled. Really peculiar and hard to debug.

**Update:**

I put a test in the vertex shader to see if the bounds are outside at that stage and they are not. When we reach the fragment shader, the bounds are outside. This means my UV coordinates are being made imprecise between the vertex and fragment stage - perhaps an interpolation error?

Comment: "*All tiles are touching in a grid-like fashion*" How exactly is this taking place? That is, how are you ensuring that the tiles are "touching"? Also, are the lines that appear between tiles the same color as the background?

Comment: @NicolBolas Lines are different color to the background, as seen in the video. The background is a light blue, all tiles are black (as defined in the shader), and the flickering lines are red (as defined in the shader). If the background color was showing through, I would assume that it was just positions being stored incorrectly, but the `v_uv.x < top_left_x` condition is definitely passing so the fragment shader must be receiving UV coordinates outside of the range I specified.

Comment: You haven't shown your vertex shader or vertex setup code (VAO specification). I could make some guesses about what's going on, but without that code, they would only be guesses. Your fragment shader may be detecting the problem, but that doesn't mean it is the *source* of the problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, sorry! Let me update the question with my vertex shader and setup code. Two buffers, both are filled in the same manner. I updated with some more information. Yes, the fragment shader has the problem but I am stuck trying to find out where the coordinates are slightly off to begin with. Another video showing the flickering colors (which I have set to white), this time with textures: https://gfycat.com/TotalSevereCopepod

Comment: Your shaders don't modify or calculate `uv` coordinates. So the issue should come where you calculate them, likely before filling the buffer.

Comment: @Ripi2 That's what I would have thought, but I just added an edit (see post) and the only two UV values uploaded are 0.125 and 0.1875 with no other places modifying them... starting to wonder if there is something in the driver/hardware which doesn't use floats to store the UV values thus they end up imprecise? Very frustrating.

Comment: Imprecision with floats is always there. With `0.125` there shouldn't be any problem, it has exact representation... Anyhow, if you can afford a bit of imprecision in your shaders, I'd do comparisons like `if (abs(value-target) < tolerance)`.

Comment: @Ripi2 I understand and I could potentially fix this using array textures and clamping them, but it is really bugging me _why_ there is an imprecision to start with. I upload one set of values and OpenGL suddenly decides that I will receive an imprecise value. It's almost as if between the vertex shader and fragment shader, e.g. in rasterization, it screws up my UV coordinates by a tiny fractional amount. Maybe this is just the way it was implemented on my drivers and hardware. Baffled.

Comment: The FS receives interpolated values from the VS. Perhaps imprecision comes from the interpolation process. Also, to discard a buffer issue, put a test in the VS, for example, changing radically the `uv` and handling this special case in the FS.

Comment: @Ripi2 That's a good idea. I put a test in the vertex shader to see if the coordinates given are ever out of bounds, and they never are. Then in the fragment shader, they are. My UV coordinates are being changed between the vertex and fragment stages without any input from me! :(

Comment: I don't see how you can conclude that there are no numerical issues just because 0.125 can be exactly represented. The fragment shader inputs are interpolated across the triangle using barycentric coordinates, so you end up with `V= (a*V1 + b*V2 c*V3)`. In a perfect world, barycentric coordinates `a`,`b`,`c` should add up to exactly 1.0. However, in the world of floating point, you can not guarantee that. The precision of floats is much higher towards zero.

Comment: @derhass I agree there's a numerical issue. I should have specified that I meant there was no numerical issue on my side of inputting numbers, sorry. You're suggesting that this is caused by a slight imprecision in the interpolation process?

Comment: After seing your videos, it seems a problem of matching between pixel position and texture coordinates, As @derhass pointed, `a,b,c` may change when you move the camera, and interpolation gets into action. Wich are you min/mag/wrap texture parameters?

Comment: @Ripi2 Remember, even when I replace the texture with a solid black color the lines appear as shown in one video so the texture itself shouldn't have anything to do with it. Nevertheless, I have tried `GL_LINEAR` and glGenerateMipmaps, all of which have the same error. All tiles are shrunk from 128x128px and so they are always minified. Adding a margin to the UV coordinates theoretically works, but feels hacky.

Comment: Perhaps the triangle verts are shifting slightly due to transformation so they don't align anymore? Would changing the geometry to an indexed triangle strip and glDrawElements fix it?